# Column valiudation - restrict one choice based on another choice

Tags: list, column, validation

Is there an OOTB way using validation / forumula to restrict choices in Column B based on the choice selected in Column A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no OOB to disable choices on the UI.

For this you need to use JavaScript or build a custom form using InfoPath. Another option is to build a cascading dropdown's using Lookup Fields (That is a bit involved and it will make UI clean)

While submitting the item you can use list validation and use a formula.

Ex: `=If([ColumnA]="Choice1", If([ColumnB]<>"Choice1", false, true), true)`